# Move element with responsive CSS in GWT

Tags: html, css, gwt

I have three elements like this in GWT:

```
HorizontalPanel picturePanel = new HorizontalPanel();
picturePanel.setStylePrimaryName("picturePanel");
image.setStylePrimaryName("picture");
leftArrow.setStylePrimaryName("arrow-left");
rightArrow.setStylePrimaryName("arrow-right");
picturePanel.add(leftArrow);
picturePanel.add(image);
picturePanel.add(rightArrow);
```

Which currently becomes the following structure after the GWT compilation:

```
<table class="picture-container">
    ...
    <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
        <img class="arrow-left" src="../images/icons/left2.svg"></img>
    </td>
    <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
        <img class="picture mission-picture" src="../pictures/d5edc879-fe9b-4980-92e3-9bb4ac020abb.jpg"></img>
    </td>
    <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
        <img class="arrow-right" src="../images/icons/right2.svg"></img>
    </td>
</table>
```

This HTML structure might very well(hopefully) be changed in the next version of GWT. To the question, **is it possible to write CSS for this (without caring about the current HTML structure) so that the arrow-left and arrow-right will appear centered underneath the image, instead of on the sides?** Note that the size of the picture is dynamic. I preferably don't want to change the GWT code as the CSS code is to be used only when the page gets smaller than a certain width, like

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {
    .arrow-left{}
    .arrow-right{}
}
```

**Update:**

I've tried a different approach by having a ResizeHandler in the GWT code that moves the arrows to a different panel underneath the image once the width becomes smaller than 420px. It works, but I think it would be a lot more efficient and handy to have it in the CSS. This solution feels a bit like an ugly hack and it makes me sad.

Here is a jsfiddle where you can try the described the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/YZSAr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** A [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/nyaray/ExMVD/3/) can be viewed on JSFiddle.

**Long version**:
First, you need to surround the images with SimplePanel instances (in GWT) that have different CSS classes, for example, `arrow-container-left` and `arrow-container-right`, respectively.

The css would then need to be as follows:

```
.picture-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;

    background-color: yellow;
}

.picture {
    display: block;
    min-width: 190px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

    background: #fa0; /* orange */
}

.arrow-container-left,
.arrow-container-right {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -65px;
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 66px;

    background-color: green;
}

.arrow-container-right {
    right: 0;
}

.arrow-left {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 62px;

    background-color: red;
}

.arrow-right {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 62px;

    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Table elements like td and tr tend to be hard to position and alter using CSS. I frequently get into these kinds of problems when using different web frameworks and often I either have to modify the source code (if I have access to it) or hack it using CSS/Javascript.

Even though you want a solution using CSS I would consider solving it in Javascript. For example with:

```
$('img.picture').parents('tbody').append(
  $('<tr></tr>').append(
    $('td .arrow-left, td .arrow-right').parent()
  )
);
```

This code removes the  elements containing images with .arrow-right and .arrow-left, then inserts them both into a new row below the row containing img.picture.

So this is also a hack that should make you sad, I actually shed some tears while writing this reply, but hopefully it will make you less sad than the ResizeHandler hack.

Here's a fiddle of the result: http://jsfiddle.net/YZSAr/5/

Comment: This will not work for me for a few reasons, first I can't depend on the current HTML structure as it might change and secondly this will, as I understand it, move the arrows permanently and stay underneath the picture when the page is resized. So it would have to have a listener too. Thanks for the effort though!

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can write CSS without assuming the HTML structure. Also, I have always thought that HorizontalPanel (as well as VerticalPanel) in GWT is supposed to be rendered as table and that won't be changing.

Why won't you use the [FlowPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FlowPanel.html) instead? It puts all its elements into divs which will make them trivial to style in your case, I suppose.

Comment: How would it be easier to position the divs?